# Google API iFrame for cross browser compatibility

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, browser

This is a quick question. I'm developing a website, and it looks amazing in google chrome, not so much in firefox, and internet explorer is terrible. I was speaking to a friend and he said that there is a chrome iframe, which if I put the contents of my website inside, it will behave like chrome on all browsers. Does anybody know of this?

Comment: I think it is called Google Chrome Frame. However the problem is that it is dependant on if the user has it installed or not, is there a way to host the frame on my domain, and force it to be used when viewing my web page?

Comment: No, the user has to install it themselves.